# Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open.

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition**. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is called *open* if it is a union of open intervals.

Example. Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not open.

How can I show to use the definition? Can you give a hint?

Comment: every open ball has irrational numbers

Comment: @Alladin Can you explain that why every open balls has irrational numbers?

Comment: For example, $a$ and $b$ real numbers, $ I = (a,b)$. We know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, find  $p$ and $q$ integers numbers such that $a <\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{2} < b$, note that     $\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number.

Comment: @Alladin Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $\mathbb Q$ is a union of open intervals; let $I$ be one of them and let $a,b \in I$. Now construct an irrational number $x$ such that $a < x < b$, so that $x \in I$, a contradiction.

Comment: But $x\not\in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

Comment: @Kahler Yes, that is the contradiction: on the one hand, $x \not \in \mathbb Q$, but on the other hand, $x \in I \subset \mathbb Q$.

Comment: $I$ is subset of  $\mathbb{R}$, is it?

Comment: @Kahler Yes. To write out my hint more explicitly: Suppose that $\mathbb Q$ is a union of open intervals of $\mathbb R$; let $I$ be one of them (so $I \subset \mathbb R$), ...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}$ is open, so $\mathbb{Q}^c$, the set of irrational numbers, is closed. Consider the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ given by $x_{n} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$. Note that $x_{n}  \in \mathbb{Q}^c$ for all $n$, and $x_{n} \to 0$, but $0 \notin \mathbb{Q}^c$, contradiction.